# How to link the libraries and the cpp of a class in a project on Visual Studio Code C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, libraries

I am new with this IDE i have generated the project with an addon. i have used Net Beans for my projects usually. I also wanted to know if there would be any option to link the libraries in any way as NET Beans does or in some project options.

I have this launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [       
    {
        "name": "Debug",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "linux": {
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main"
        },
        "osx": {
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "lldb-mi",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main"
        },
        "windows": {
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "gdb.exe",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main.exe"
        },
        "preLaunchTask": "build"
    }
]
```

}